# Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi Get Build Status Launched by PR policy

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, pull-request

In our pipeline we programmatically create a pull request (PR). The branch being merged into has a policy on it that launches a build. This build takes a variable amount of time. I need to query the build status until it is complete (or long timeout) so that I can complete the PR, and clean up the temp branch.

I am trying to figure out how to get the build that was kicked off by the PR so that I can inspect the status by using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi, but all overloads of BuildHttpClientBase.GetBuildAsync require a build Id which I don't have. I would like to avoid using the Azure Build REST API. Does anyone know how I might get the Build kicked off by the PR without the build ID using BuildHttpClientBase?

Unfortunately the documentation doesn't offer a lot of detail about functionality.

Comment: if you're using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi` you ARE using the REST API. Those libraries are just SDKs that make REST API interaction easier.

Comment: True which is why I was surprised that the SDK doesn't seem to have a way to query for a build without the build Id, because it seems that you can from the API.

Comment: Oh I see your confusion, over the statement that I want to avoid using the rest api. What I mean is that I don't want to construct Rest API calls myself, and would prefer to use the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answering the question you asked:

Finding a call that provides the single deterministic build id for a pull request doesn't seem to be very readily available.

As mentioned, you can use `BuldHttpClient.GetBuildsAsync()` to filter builds based on branch, repository, requesting user and reason.

Adding the `BuildReason.PullRequest` value in the request is probably redundant according to the branch you will need to pass.

```cs
var pr = new GitPullRequest(); // the PR you've received after creation
var requestedFor = pr.CreatedBy.DisplayName;
var repo = pr.Repository.Id.ToString();
var branch = $"refs/pull/{pr.PullRequestId}/merge";
var reason = BuildReason.PullRequest;

var buildClient = c.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
var blds = await buildClient.GetBuildsAsync("myProject", 
                                            branchName: branch,
                                            repositoryId: repo,
                                            requestedFor: requestedFor,
                                            reasonFilter: reason,
                                            repositoryType: "TfsGit");
```

In your question you mentioned wanting the build (singular) for the pull request, which implies that you only have one build definition acting as the policy gate. This method can return multiple Build**s** based on the policy configurations on your target branch. However, if that were your setup, it would seem logical that your question would then be asking for all those related builds for which you would wait to complete the PR.

I was looking into [Policy Evaluations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/evaluations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to see if there was a more straight forward way to get the id of the build being run via policy, but I haven't been able to format the request properly as per:

> Evaluations are retrieved using an artifact ID which uniquely identifies the pull request. To generate an artifact ID for a pull request, use this template:
>
> `vstfs:///CodeReview/CodeReviewId/{projectId}/{pullRequestId}`

Even using the value that is returned in the `artifactId` field on the PR using the GetById method results in a `Doesn't exist or Don't have access` response, so if someone else knows how to use this method and if it gives exact build ids being evaluated for the policy configurations, I'd be glad to hear it.

---

### An alternative to get what you actually desire

It sounds like the only use you have for the branch policy is to run a "gate build" before completing the merge.

Why not [create the PR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#request-body) with autocomplete.

> **Name** - autoCompleteSetBy
>
> **Type** - IdentityRef
>
> **Description** - If set, auto-complete is enabled for this pull request and this is the identity that enabled it.

```cs
var me = new IdentityRef(); // you obviously need to populate this with real values
var prClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
await prClient.CreatePullRequestAsync(new GitPullRequest()
                                      {
                                          CreatedBy = me,
                                          AutoCompleteSetBy = me,
                                          Commits = new GitCommitRef[0],
                                          SourceRefName = "feature/myFeature",
                                          TargetRefName = "master",
                                          Title = "Some good title for my PR"
                                      },
                                      "myBestRepository",
                                      true);
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for taking the time to answer. So while this is a good idea, and it is actually the way I am going to approach this problem (choosing to write a separate program to deal with clean up and not worry about monitoring the build at all) it is not solving the original problem so I don't think that I should mark it as the answer. However I do think I found what I was originally looking for. BuildHttpClientBase.GetBuildsAsync (notice the plural builds). This actually has the nullable query params that I expected from GetBuild, but had missed it.

Comment: If you would like the points for this answer, would you want to add another answer with the GetBuildsAsync? I feel like you deserve them. With this method I would be able to get a list of builds based on branch, user who submitted, and potentially min and  maxTime. This should allow me to find the build without it's ID. I was expecting though that there should be a way to find any builds on the PR object which would give a definite result, and surprised that I couldn't find any.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with how I've gone about finding the build without the build id, which is pretty much how you've mentioned. As per not finding the build on a PR, I think it's because the build isn't actually part of the PR, but part of the policy on the branch being merged to.